# MSSQL to MySQL migration slowdown .NET WinFrm application performance

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, winforms, mysql-workbench

I have developed a .net based desktop application (WinFrm) using C# and MS SQL Server. I have used Typed DataSets with Stored Procedures to connect MSSQL  database. Now i have migrated MSSQL database to MySQL database as per client requirements. But i find it too slow (While uploading excel files, and normal select operations over remote connection). I have used MySQL Installer 5.6.13 for Windows that includes MySQL Workbench, and i have migrated MSSQL database using MySQL Workbench. Do i need to change any thing else in the code to speedup its performance with MySQL?

Note:- MySQL Workbench is installed on Microsoft Windows Server 2008R2 and application accessing it remotely.

Comment: I don't know how much time difference you came across but did a little Google search and found out you are not the only one discovers Mysql is slower than MSSQL. However, if it is not a bit but too slow, something else might be wrong?

Comment: simple select and update operations are also slower then sql server, i change only MySQL Connection related things in the code and TypedDataSets Configuration with MySQL

Comment: @Kuzgun, i did a small check (a select statement) with timer, MS SQL one is taking 294ms while the same code with MySQL is taking 2237ms to return result.